# detect whether data exist in field with unique constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database

There is a field(named `nickname` for example)in the table with unique constraint, that means it is impassable to insert a same nickname into the table.So before insert a nickname I should know whether the nickname exist in the field,there are two ways to deal with this issue, I want to know which one is better.

```
1. (Only one SQL)   
    Insert data directly, then catch the database error code(in MySQL is 1586) to judge whether duplicate keys exist. 
2. (One or two SQL, and select maybe scan full table)
    Query the table first then decide to insert or not.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, because this error case is so specific, just catch the database exception and react to it. This could cause issues if there is more than one unique field in the table like `nickname` though.

If there is more than one that could throw the same exception, you may want to be more specific, and that may mean running a query up front.